# How to plot y=|sinx||cosx| without the use of a graphing calcuator?

Tags: trigonometry, graphing-functions

Just substitute known values? Or is there a better way around this?!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Guide:

$$y=|\sin x||\cos x|= \frac12 |\color{blue}{2 \sin x \cos x}|$$

Now, identify a double angle formula to simplify the expression.

Comment: :) thanks a lot

Answer (score 1):

You can use a cathode-ray tube oscilloscope and drive the deflection electrodes with a triangular signal horizontally and a sinusoidal one vertically, but the latter should be rectified. The two signals must be synchronous and units understood so that the horizontal period is $\pi$ and vertical range $\frac12$.

[image]

The triangular signal can be obtained by integration of a constant tension and reset logics, and the sinusoid by means of an LC oscillator.
(I must admit that this is a kind of analogic calculator, though.)

Comment: i have to be honest, this is beyond me

Comment: @Dudeness: don't worry, it's a joke.

Comment: explains why i asked such a dumb question lol